# htaccess rewrite subdomain to some folder if exists else another

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know there are some similar questions about subdomain -> folder htaccess, but I already have a setup that works for me for that simple case.

What I want to add, is "rewrite to projects/*subdomain*/current/public/ if that current/public exists, else rewrite to projects/*subdomain*/"

It's because I'm hosting a laravel application, which is in 'public/', and I deployed it using a tool that symlinks 'current/' to its latest release.

My current setup is:

```
# Redirect everything non-www to /projects/...
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.mydomain\.com
RewriteCond /var/www/mydomain.com/projects/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /projects/%1/$1 [L]
```

Which is something like:

- if it doesn't start with www
- get the subdomain in a var
- if the /projects/*subdomain* folder exists
- rewrite the request to look into that folder
- else 404

How would I update this to have an "IF /projects/*subdomain*/current/public exists, then that, ELSE IF /projects/*subdomain* exists, then that, ELSE 404"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create another rule *before* the existing one. For example, following the same pattern as your existing rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect to /projects/<subdomain>/current/public/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.mydomain\.com
RewriteCond /var/www/mydomain.com/projects/%1/current/public -d
RewriteRule (.*) /projects/%1/current/public/$1 [L]

# Redirect everything non-www to /projects/...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.mydomain\.com
RewriteCond /var/www/mydomain.com/projects/%1 -d
RewriteRule (.*) /projects/%1/$1 [L]
```

I removed the `^` from the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (`^(.*)`) since it was superfluous.

I also changed `!^www.*` (matches any hostname that simply starts "www") to `!^www\.` (any hostname that starts "www." - the subdomain only) to avoid potentially spurious matches.

Presumably `/var/www/mydomain.com` is the document-root, so you could use the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` server variable instead in the `RewriteCond` *TestString*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/projects/%1/current/public -d
```

However, by themselves, these directives will result in a rewrite-loop (500 error), so I assume you already have directives in place that prevent this. eg. Another `.htaccess` file in the directory that you are rewriting to that contains mod_rewrite directives (relevant to the individual projects)? If not then you can either add another condition to each rule that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable, or include an *exception* at the top of the file that prevents further processing after the request is rewritten. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Stop further processing if the request has already been rewritten
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

: Remaining directives follow...
```

**UPDATE:** If you are on Apache 2.4 you can instead simply change the `L` flag to `END` to halt all processing by the rewrite engine, to prevent a rewrite loop. The `END` flag is a relatively recent addition and consequently often gets overlooked - but it's not strictly necessary as there are always other (perhaps more complex) ways to do this.

> Why would it loop?

The `L` flag does not stop all processing. It simply stops the current round of processing and then the rewrite engine effectively starts over, passing the rewritten URL back into the *rewrite engine*. In the above example, the rewritten URL also matches the same rules, so the URL would be rewritten again, and again, and again, ....

For example (for simplicity, just using your original rule that rewrites to `/projects`):

1. Request `subdomain.mydomain.com/foo`
2. `<doc-root>/projects/subdomain` directory exists
3. URL rewritten to `/projects/subdomain/foo`
4. Rewriting process starts over... passing in the rewritten URL, essentially `subdomain.mydomain.com/projects/subdomain/foo`, back into the rewrite engine.
5. `<doc-root>/projects/subdomain` directory exists (as previous)
6. URL rewritten to `/projects/subdomain/projects/subdomain/foo`
7. Rewriting process starts over... etc. etc.

The Rewriting process loops in this fashion until the URL passes through unchanged, unless something else steps in the way... for example, as mentioned above, if you have another `.htaccess` file located at `/projects/subdomain/.htaccess` that also contains mod_rewrite directives then control would pass to this `.htaccess` file after the first round of rewrite processing and prevent further rewrites (since mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default).

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent an hour with "skip rule" checks and whatnot, to create an if-branch and whatnot, debugging all of that, and it's just so simple. The only thing i don't fully understand in your answer is the last part, about the rewrite-loop. Why would it loop? It doesn't appear to be, in my test projects at least..

Comment: I've updated my answer explaining the potential rewrite-loop.

Comment: Thanks for the update and the example! But then I wonder how it ever worked, because it did... I haven't had errors about infinite loops in my previous structure, and I've used it for at least 5 of those projects, which don't have .htaccess files in them

Comment: "which don't have .htaccess files in them" - or any other `.htaccess` files along the filesystem path? Or directives in the server config? I think there must be something somewhere... (eg. simply enabling the rewrite engine in a subdirectory would be sufficient.)